# Again problem retrieving data for firebase kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, child-process

I can't see what I'm doing wrongly

The only thing I want is retrieves all the childs under Publicaciones, but It doesn´t retrieve anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c9UH.jpg)

My code should work. I think but it nevers enter into de onDataChange. The rest of the code it's not important here.

```
private fun mostrarFotosSubidas(){
    val publcacionesRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Publicaciones")
    publcacionesRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            //if (snapshot.exists())
            listaPublicacion!!.clear()
            for (snapshot in snapshot.children)
            {
                val publicacion = snapshot.getValue(Publicacion::class.java)
                if (publicacion != null) {
                    if (publicacion.equals(uidRecibido)) {
                        (listaPublicacion as ArrayList<Publicacion>).add(publicacion)
                    }
                    listaPublicacion!!.reverse()
                    imagenesAdaptador!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }




        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the error message that comes from the `error` object?

Comment: How can I log that error? I'm completely a noob

Comment: You can use `Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage())`.